# Android get token of google drive using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-drive-api, access-token

I'm using Google Drive API in my android application. I'm using GoogleApiClient like below:

```
private GoogleApiClient buildApiClient() {
    return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
```

I need get access token. How can I do this using GoogleApiClient if it's possible? Or I need another way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Google for Android documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview). According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth), `GoogleAuthUtil` provides ClientLogin, OAuth2, ID, or offline token for Google accounts. That being said, if you're instead using the Google Play services library to access Google APIs such as Play Game services, you don't need an OAuth 2.0 token and you can instead access these services using the `GoogleApiClient`. For more information, read [Accessing Google Play Services APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client). You can decide which one will better fit your use case. Best of Luck!